# Handling concurrent call to conversational components on JBoss Seam

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, seam

I'm working on a project using JBoss Seam 2.2.6, JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.

Users of the application must enter data in a form, and for certain fields it is necessary to make calls to the backend to recalculate other values ​​based on the data entered.

Back-end calls are made using the AJAX support RichFaces offers, for example, using `<a4j: support>` for onchange events.

This is the Jsf/RichFaces code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{managedBean.someValue}" >
         <s:selectItems value="#{managedBean.entityList}" var="_item"
               label="#{_item.label}"
                itemValue="{item.value}"
           />
          <a4j:support 
                event="onchange"          //  handling onchange event
                status="waitStatus"       //  "please wait.." pop up blocks UI
                eventsQueue="afjQueue"    //  ajax requests queue
                ignoreDupResposes="true"  //  avoid similar requests
                action="#{managedBean.onInputChange()}"
                reRender="somePanel"
                oncomplete="showErrors();"
            />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem is that the user could click on different fields of the form or on different buttons, make multiple requests to the server in a short period of time, and Seam does not support concurrent calls to the same **conversation scoped component** (if it happened a [ConcurrentCallToConversation](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/190446) error would occur )

To avoid this we have done the following:

1) adding a [a4j:queue](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_queue.html) for queueing AJAX requests

2) setting `ignoreDupResposes="true"` to avoid "similar" requests.

3) setting seam core property `concurrent-request-timeout="5000"` ([info about this property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868717/practical-value-for-concurrent-request-timeout-parameter-or-options-for-avoiding). This property causes a request to have exclusive control of the component for 5 seconds)

4) adding a [a4j:status](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_status.html) that shows a "please wait..." dialog between request starts and request ends, blocking the UI

Because the user experience is affected by a pop up that appears every time an ajax request is made, **i want to delete the alternative 4.**

So my question is: **Is it guaranteed that there will** **not occur a concurrent call to conversation** if I use a queue of requests and a large enough timeout for exclusive access? meaning that using **the first 3 items would be enough**.